# Discord Py - Bacckground tasks for unbanning temporarily banned users, perform unban in specific server

Tags: python, discord, scheduled-tasks, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord moderation bot, and I am struggling with having temporary bans setup. I have a background task checking to see what date a user was temporarily banned within a csv file and if its been 3 days then unban the user. I have the whole task working as expected, but cannot for the life of me figure out how to unban the user without context.

```
import asyncio
import discord
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from discord.ext import commands, tasks


class Events(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client  # this allows us to access the client within our cog

    # ------------------- Events and Tasks -------------------
    # Loads bot, and lets us know when its ready
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        self.ban_check.start()
        print("Logged in as " + self.client.user.name)
        print(self.client.user.id)
        print("-------")

    # When a known command fails, throws error
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx, error):
        await ctx.send(ctx.command.name + " didn't work! Give it another try.")
        print(error)

    # Event for monitoring command usage
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command(self, ctx):
        print(ctx.command.name + " was invoked.")

    # Event for monitoring successful command usage
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_completion(self, ctx):
        print(ctx.command.name + " was invoked sucessfully.")

    # Task loop to check if its been 3 days since a ban and unbans the user
    @tasks.loop()
    async def ban_check(self):

        for guild in self.client.guilds:

            guild = guild.id

            print(guild)
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            print("Automatic Task is Running...")
            print("CHECKING BAN LIST")
            df = pd.read_csv('database.csv')
            # member = df["User_ID"]
            bandate = df["Tempban"]

            for date in bandate:
                if str(date) != "nan":
                    print(date)
                    d1 = dt.datetime.strptime(str(date), "%Y-%m-%d")
                    d2 = dt.datetime.strptime(str(dt.date.today()), "%Y-%m-%d")
                    delta = (d2 - d1).days
                    print(delta)

                    if delta >= 3:
                        # guild = self.client.get_guild()
                        print('-------------')
                        user = df.loc[df["Tempban"] == date, "User_ID"]
                        # await self.client.unban(user)
                        # await self.client.guild.unban(user)
                        await discord.Guild.unban(user, guild)
                        print(user)
                    # warnings = int(df.loc[df["User_ID"] == member.id, "Infractions"])
                else:
                    continue


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Events(client))
```

Any suggestions to get me in the right direction would be extremely appreciated.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/MenuDocs/Discord.PY-Tutorials/blob/Episode-21/cogs/moderation.py#L39) as an example for fetching/getting objects and change for your code accordingly

Comment: @EthanM-H I took a look at what you provided and have made some major changes to my code, but I can't seem to get it to perform the unban action in the specified server. I believe I have the correct syntax, but I keep getting an object has no attribute 'unban' for any of the things i try. Any other suggestions?

Comment: You need to call unban on an instance of `Guild`, not the reference to the class.

`await ctx.guild.unban(user)` type of thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to create an object to get this working.

I used this

```
await guild.unban(discord.Object(id=user_id))
```

instead of

```
await discord.Guild.unban(user, guild)
```